# Product attributes don't work on frontend when "Any variation" is used

Tags: woocommerce

When I use "Any variation"and I don't add each variation for a product in the admin custom, after choosing the desired attribute variation in the front-end, and pressing the Buy button, the selection disappears and nothing happens.

Really no idea what could be causing this and when it started as a couple of months ago it definitely worked both ways..

Could this be a Woocommerce bug?

Wordpress version: 4.9.9
Woocommerce version: 3.6.3

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Updated to Wordpress 5.2 and tried deactivating all plugins which are also updated - nothing helps.

Comment: Something which may be of importance - when I'm logged as administrator, I'm able to choose a variation and simulate a purchase on the front-end successfully. Visitors however are not able to purchase